# Programmatically display child ViewController of TabBar element (and pass data)

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want my users to be redirected to a specific view controller when they click on a notification.
The view controller they are redirected to depends on the notification data.

I am using FCM so I implemented the required functions in the AppDelegate.

Then I implemented the redirection to a viewcontroller when clicking on a notification (in the *userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)* method).

My app has a tabBarController with 4 view controllers (Activities -> TableView, Events, On Sale, My City).
I managed to display the My City ViewController but I don't know how to pass data.

Then, I would also like for some notifications, to display a single activity (Activities VC -> single activity). I managed to display the Activities VC but not a single Activity

```
// Display 'My City' without passing data (something I would like to do)

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBar:UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
tabBar.selectedIndex = 4
self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


// Display Single activity (without the Navigation Controller Top Bar and the bottom Tab Bar; and without passing data => 2 issues)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SingleActivityVC")
self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

So it works when I click on the notification, these two pages are displayed, but :

1- For 'My City', I can't pass data with my current code

2- For the single activity VC : I can't pass data and I don't know how to keep the navigation elements (top and bottom bars)

Answer (score 1):

For your second issue, the navigation bar and the tab bar are not being displayed because you are only instantiating the SingleActivityVC and setting it as the root.
Instead you need to instantiate the parent tab bar controller, select the index of the tab that contains the activities view controller you want, and then call a method on it that will send you to the SingleActivityVC you are looking for.

From your code:

```
let tabBar:UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController

tabBar.selectedIndex = 4

if let item = tabBar.viewControllers?[tabBar.selectedIndex] as? SomeViewController{
    item.goToSingleActivity(with: "some data")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try for you pass data in 'My City'

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBar:UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
tabBar.selectedIndex = 4

let myCityVC = tabBar.viewControllers![3] as! myCityViewController
myCityVC.myProperty = awesomeValue

self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```